# How to iterate values of map in Scala?

Tags: scala

For the value 
`val m = Map(2 ->(3, 2), 1 ->(2, 1))` 
I want to add up elements belonged to same key, thus, the result is : 
`Map(2 -> 5,1 -> 3)` 
 Please guys help me how to solve this problem, I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: have u tried any code ??

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
m.mapValues { case(x,y) => x+y }
```

which creates a new `Map` with same keys and computed values. Also consider

```
def f(t: (Int,Int)) = t._1+t._2
```

and so a more concise approach includes this

```
m.mapValues(f)
```

Note [Decomposing tuples in function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11615740/3189923) for details in declaring a function that can take the tuples from the `Map`.

**Update** Following important note by @KevinMeredith (see link in comment below), `mapValues` provides a view to the collection and the transformation needs be referentially transparent; hence as a standard (intuitive) approach consider pattern-matching on the entire key-value group using `map` for instance like this,

```
m.map { case (x,(t1,t2)) => x -> (t1+t2) }
```

or

```
m.map { case (k,v) => (k,f(v)) }
```

or

```
for ( (x,(t1,t2)) <- m ) yield x -> (t1+t2)
```

Comment: Take a look at http://blog.bruchez.name/2013/02/mapmap-vs-mapmapvalues.html if using `mapValues`